# Is There a Way to Make A More Granular Heatmap with ggmap in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap, ggmap

I'm trying to make a heatmap of locations using latitude and longitude. My map works but the points in an area are being grouped together too much. What I want is something like what I have but with the heat traced much more granularly so that you can see smaller differences between places.

This is the relevant code:

```
bbox <- c(left = -79.1, bottom = 38, right = -71.8, top = 41.5)

coords.map <- get_stamenmap(bbox, zoom = 9, maptype = "toner-lite")
coords.map <- ggmap(coords.map, extent="device", legend="none")


coords.map <- coords.map + stat_density2d(data=recruits2,  
  aes(x=MailingLong, y=MailingLat, fill=..level.., alpha=..level..), 
  bins = 20, geom = "polygon")
coords.map <- coords.map + scale_fill_gradientn(colours=rev(brewer.pal(20, "Spectral")))

coords.map <- coords.map + theme_bw()
coords.map
```

This is what I'm getting
[image]

Edit: Here is the first 200 rows of recruits from dput

```
structure(list(MailingLong = c(-77.024196799, -77.003914977, 
-76.800101376, -77.116797729, -77.018188811, -77.120614114, -76.975844627, 
-77.147034967, -77.089368856, -76.97864858, -76.844030329, -76.9639802739999, 
-77.257533391, -76.822314419, -80.0753704429999, -76.551298185, 
-76.767346001, -78.7422733669999, -77.2918568269999, -74.252185664, 
-77.035277127, -76.957338864, -77.403195991, -77.6319986669999, 
-73.944649177, -76.5599475129999, -73.571443862, -76.989599958, 
-76.8866457089999, -76.8900467889999, -77.027862935, -76.763716223, 
-74.035259712, -77.075101833, -76.9065139969999, -77.009444624, 
-76.991265512, -76.998362508, -77.0138546809999, -76.92147388, 
-76.937957008, -73.897316132, -77.2021361069999, -76.9865863379999, 
-77.057626187, -77.2698420199999, -73.962312531, -77.061793597, 
-74.118483634, -73.8812691919999, -84.1753095879999, -76.849177244, 
-76.9494415629999, -77.011200646, -77.12310071, -76.8884595649999, 
-77.0061180499999, -77.017453829, -76.946342907, -76.980566735, 
-76.923624123, -77.010469798, -77.02638151, -76.918852741, -76.9224746959999, 
-87.802292575, -76.813914677, -73.9355411179999, -77.0086792399999, 
-76.9349190729999, -77.020158344, -76.9487103719999, -73.846362546, 
-77.015177632, -80.255301241, -77.428318142, -77.0007635819999, 
-76.929540264, -76.947718204, -76.93487089, -77.019630846, -77.018265258, 
-73.893035738, -76.887356744, -74.746807223, -76.825205743, -76.8953029259999, 
-76.962229153, -77.0435782929999, -73.844867129, -76.926558429, 
-76.8879371259999, -73.8547164669999, -76.920915296, -81.556675863, 
-77.088045767, -76.8971086939999, -73.2218500929999, -77.283520263, 
-77.0097035049999, -73.995325534, -82.7629230599999, -76.952207819, 
-77.012592416, -77.0260711729999, -76.942692268, -76.981824075, 
-73.261707374, -77.0867976709999, -76.904238182, -77.172019128, 
-76.9965300979999, -77.0255964739999, -76.984859179, -76.9812736649999, 
-77.081601215, -76.759961416, -74.6169999639999, -77.043506263, 
-77.202603773, -76.949909772, -76.9530278129999, -76.7527797119999, 
-75.053749344, -76.746774219, -71.778088926, -77.02110899, -76.854547506, 
-77.084631879, -76.997437527, -76.901572162, -73.870879122, -76.878514023, 
-74.1344631809999, -74.318660444, -82.7075784359999, -74.7182968279999, 
-76.797062055, -77.5707813399999, -77.6124343819999, -75.5027960319999, 
-76.987749881, -76.9821815619999, -75.828326588, -79.783059322, 
-76.9499001519999, -80.259390617, -77.117644909, -77.2343587779999, 
-73.8982356609999, -77.472350213, -76.9425510419999, -76.977082436, 
-76.9939519549999, -77.1868244199999, -74.7314534239999, -76.965619788, 
-77.007779215, -76.967062614, -76.951343771, -77.396949305, -76.999679182, 
-76.9883032339999, -77.0871543499999, -76.901727819, -77.106636225, 
-75.01563442, -84.127288743, -84.4811913569999, -88.267507704, 
-77.011828453, -74.081075439, -72.669365125, -73.007336905, -76.923843066, 
-77.019205179, -76.9821401839999, -73.927507514, -77.0365238109999, 
-76.695715095, -76.871854318, -76.831811042, -75.341965451, -74.0187008359999, 
-76.851878874, -72.8766466989999, -76.9806527699999, -77.327771618, 
-73.9872406649999, -73.9230185489999, -74.127273734, -74.050468364, 
-77.044012991, -74.068816409, -73.950062444, -76.874810759, -76.976120023, 
-77.0778578119999, -77.410060892, -104.726662525), MailingLat = c(38.9681180370001, 
38.728353848, 38.795798179, 38.8259334890001, 38.7331564900001, 
38.8947512510001, 38.5234046750001, 38.8229569550001, 38.85372949, 
38.9289913380001, 39.2386466790001, 38.929587806, 38.7748015860001, 
39.4697715190001, 40.4490489200001, 39.126109242, 38.808320123, 
35.80390168, 38.605807435, 40.1699337740001, 38.6193497140001, 
38.922676057, 38.6439925450001, 39.9533144690001, 40.7054857840001, 
39.345963984, 41.1666994920001, 38.81984234, 38.9428468840001, 
38.733140373, 38.982152528, 38.824874175, 40.1742035030001, 38.78925345, 
39.0010581130001, 38.9664260480001, 38.8579487740001, 38.946905756, 
38.8784059170001, 38.902325202, 38.911513062, 40.9063276460001, 
38.8638673040001, 38.9097773670001, 38.9240989080001, 38.8797625300001, 
40.5770966100001, 38.792493279, 40.6751541570001, 42.8175953150001, 
33.5073237140001, 38.9272529080001, 38.8836017150001, 38.8243908630001, 
38.8446904240001, 38.8658511960001, 38.917771981, 38.938885574, 
38.8719206270001, 38.885876071, 38.8924471080001, 38.833980207, 
38.9562671210001, 38.8918037330001, 38.876033218, 41.914514481, 
39.3841564950001, 40.8475071350001, 38.8235965260001, 38.9344933350001, 
39.0245538930001, 38.639340094, 42.666483283, 38.7850074940001, 
36.093245149, 38.210712964, 38.8477400190001, 38.888638916, 38.867858267, 
38.8906912090001, 38.929587746, 38.9521219760001, 40.8675224940001, 
38.8787024690001, 41.140377415, 38.804541885, 38.852253413, 38.8221755930001, 
38.9213773750001, 40.8910776750001, 38.88197389, 39.0817835830001, 
40.8247535940001, 38.8854398610001, 30.1117637080001, 39.087920518, 
38.940159973, 41.2659053740001, 38.801129729, 38.896368373, 40.8391054510001, 
33.720799115, 38.8651627890001, 38.826764516, 38.9238514780001, 
38.9046515320001, 38.925578864, 44.0306323230001, 39.035399668, 
38.5953835010001, 39.119000919, 38.9563723100001, 38.976737762, 
38.960012873, 38.934212899, 38.961016375, 38.6100870970001, 40.2422624710001, 
38.9248050900001, 38.85129355, 38.90282683, 38.8914932600001, 
38.576783327, 40.0710674210001, 38.62669212, 42.292809602, 38.956420038, 
38.845185488, 38.859804126, 38.904392242, 38.9032118310001, 40.6809593840001, 
38.887417929, 40.6499415820001, 40.9926879540001, 28.0700605050001, 
40.2071700650001, 38.761238259, 38.7582776680001, 38.8111178980001, 
39.956535079, 38.8784065950001, 38.903570121, 44.0488523160001, 
40.4418602050001, 38.9028348410001, 26.1337374180001, 38.8889284410001, 
39.185845467, 40.9479277930001, 38.769957467, 38.869303099, 38.901602515, 
38.8247793570001, 38.770411516, 40.1243989540001, 38.935076042, 
38.9514988700001, 38.87461904, 38.8908902330001, 38.457439761, 
38.8236920620001, 38.883861181, 38.938825771, 38.854090721, 38.715420469, 
40.8443550060001, 41.4013022350001, 34.0559358790001, 40.0861231000001, 
38.8252308690001, 40.729698834, 42.1328508010001, 40.9432147800001, 
38.8837031510001, 38.845665739, 38.84924341, 41.0833210810001, 
38.911186511, 39.0930236410001, 39.0773085930001, 38.990928769, 
40.633318704, 40.7794771000001, 38.946823571, 41.665512818, 38.929088312, 
38.861215551, 40.588697102, 40.830763007, 40.664786738, 41.044012874, 
39.077050066, 40.714393369, 40.5922452140001, 38.8516571170001, 
38.85133934, 39.059085399, 38.431202824, 38.7833722510001)), row.names = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 
30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
57L, 60L, 61L, 62L, 64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 
74L, 75L, 77L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 
88L, 89L, 90L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 95L, 96L, 97L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 
102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L, 117L, 118L, 120L, 121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 
125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 
138L, 140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 
162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 
173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 
184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 195L, 197L, 
198L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 212L, 
213L, 214L, 215L, 216L, 217L, 218L, 219L, 220L, 221L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it's possible. However, the specific approach is dependent on your data, which you have not included in your question, so it's difficult to know how to help you, other than suggesting that you make your example reproducible. (for example including the contents of `dput(recruits2)`

Comment: You may need to do some data treatment if a lot of your data is centered in one spot, like manually binning the less dense points into larger bins, unless there's an option for scale_fill somewhere to handle that for you, but I think all of that is generated in the kernel density estimate.